# Bundler cannot find a version of a gem, but gem install with the same name works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundler, gemfile

I've created a gem, and for some reason this one keeps bugging me, and refuses to install properly through bundler.

Here's the *Gemfile*:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.9'
gem "switch_access-rails", "~> 1.1.6"
```

*bundle install* fails with:

```
Could not find gem 'switch_access-rails (~> 1.1.6) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
```

This works:

```
gem install switch_access-rails -v 1.1.6
```

And the gem is here on rubygems: https://rubygems.org/gems/switch_access-rails/versions/1.1.6

I even tried bumping from version 1.1.5 to 1.1.6 just to see if that helped.

Installing version 1.1.4 in with bundle install works.

Any tips on where to start looking/debugging bundle install?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

And after a whole day of googling I found this status update from Dec 12: http://twitter.com/rubygems_status/status/279019743166476288

```
bundle install --full-index
```

Seems to get the index directly from rubygems instead of from a cloudfront cache.

I had a look at the index, and there is quite a diffence in the two indexes, so if you just released a gem or use a newly released gem, you might have to add --full-index in order to get the proper index.

Comment: just happened to me with aws-sdk 3.0.1 gem

Comment: I am also having a similar issue. I tried your solution and bumped into the following issue:
`/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory`

Comment: @CuriousDeveloper This looks more like a missing setup for ruby, rbenv or rvm. Try reinstalling rbenv, ruby and/or rvm, depending on your setup, as it's missing an executable.

Comment: @leifcr, thanks for your suggestion, my issue is resolved now. I am stuck on a different issue maybe you can help me resolve it  here is the post link: https://serverfault.com/questions/941802/unable-to-push-recent-changes-to-old-ruby-website-on-heroku

Answer (score 2):

Do you have rubygems listed as a remote source?

Your `Gemfile` should have `source :rubygems` at the top of the file, and `$ gem sources` should return at a minimum:

```
*** CURRENT SOURCES ***

http://rubygems.org/
```

If it's not listed, you can add it with `$ gem sources -a http://rubygems.org`

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to copy that from my Gemfile, as I trimmed it down to a minimum. I found the answer however. Seems like cloudfront metadata caching issue on the rubygems index, as the gem was released today.